# A vertex marking another vertex, BFS VS DFS

Tags: algorithm, graph-algorithm, shortest-path, depth-first-search, breadth-first-search

The question is :

[image]

I'm pretty sure it's 2, yet i can't find a graph that will represent it, A graph that using BDS will always generate that v is marking u but in DFS u could mark v.

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0):

I think it is pretty simple. Consider this graph

```
nodes: s, u, v, a
edges: s-v, s-a, a-u, u-v
```

According to the order of nodes in `s` adjacency list sometimes `v` marks `u` and sometimes `u` marks `v`

Comment: I don't really understand how this is true. According to the question, v should mark u in BFS, but with your example, s marks both u and v so v doesn't mark u, am i missing something here ? Thanks.

Comment: The question says DFS.

Comment: "Let G be an undirected graph, Assume you run a BFS from G. During the run, the vertex v marks the vertex u." So your G is not defined as a graph that the question asks about.

Answer (score 0):

Ruling out answer (1):

Assume G be the circle graph `s-a1-a2-u-v-s`. There are 2 possible DFSes, one marks `u` before `v`, the other `v` before `u`. The information from the BFS does not rule out any one of them.

Ruling out answer (3):

The same reasoning as in the case of answer (1) applies.

Answer (2) is the only one that remains.